# Create Menu with Links in react sementic ui. I want to know installation of react for this.

Tags: reactjs

Create Menu with Links in react sementic ui. I want to know installation of react for this. I stuck on this since last week.

Can anyone suggest me quickly how can i achieve it. Waiting for response from anyone. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

**Let start with installation,**

Use CDNs,This is the quickest way to get started with Semantic UI React. You won't be able to use custom themes with this method.

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.12/semantic.min.css"></link>`

The Semantic UI React package can be installed via Yarn:

> **$ yarn add semantic-ui-react**

Semantic UI CSS can be installed as a package in your project using Yarn. You won't be able to use custom themes with this method.

> **$ yarn add semantic-ui-css**

After install, you'll need to include the minified CSS file in your index.js file:

> **import 'semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css';**

Detailed documentation on theming in Semantic UI is provided [here.][1]

> **$ yarn add semantic-ui --dev**

After building the project with Gulp, you'll need to include the minified CSS file in your index.js file:

> import '../semantic/dist/semantic.min.css';

here the Sementic Ui Menu with Link, i am using react-router Link in menu.

```js
class MenuExampleNameProp extends React.Component {
   constructor(props){
    super(props);
     this.state = {activeItem:''}
  
  this.handleItemClick = this.handleItemClick.bind(this)
  }

  handleItemClick(e, { name }){
  this.setState({ activeItem: name })
  }

  render() {
    const { activeItem } = this.state

    return (
      <Menu>
        <Menu.Item
          as={Link}
          to={'/app/editorials'}
          name='editorials'
          active={activeItem === 'editorials'}
          onClick={this.handleItemClick}
        />
        <Menu.Item
          as={Link}
          to={'/app/reviews'}
          name='reviews'
          active={activeItem === 'reviews'}
          onClick={this.handleItemClick}
        />
        <Menu.Item
          as={Link}
          to={'/app/upcomingEvents'}
          name='upcomingEvents'
          active={activeItem === 'upcomingEvents'}
          onClick={this.handleItemClick}
        />
      </Menu>
    )
  }
}
var target= document.getElementById('react-app')
ReactDOM.render(<MenuExampleNameProp/>,target)
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.12/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.24.0/babel.js"></script>
<div id="react-app"></div>
```